# New line char in qbsic?

Tags: newline, qbasic

I know that my question is very basic,but I'm not familier with qbasic,so excuse me.My question is:

How I can detect new line char in a string variable in qbasic?In java we have to find `'\n'` char,but what is in qbasic?Really I want to read a text file and detect it's lines.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `INSTR` function:

```
'Sample text
Dim myText As String
myText = "Hello World!" + CHR$(10) + "This is a new line."

'Find new line character \n (line feed LF)
Dim newLinePosition As Integer
newLinePosition = Instr(myText, CHR$(10))
If (newLinePosition >= 1) Then
    Print "Yes, a LF character was found at char no# "; Ltrim$(Str$(newLinePosition))
Else
    Print "No LF character was found. :("
End If

Sleep: End
```

The syntax of INSTR looks like this:

```
pos% = INSTR ( [startOffset%,] haystack$, needle$ )
```

If `startOffset%` is omitted, it starts its search at the begin of the String. The character you look for is `CHR$(10)`. QBasic uses this CHR-Syntax instead of the escaping known from Java etc.

Here you can find additional help on the INSTR function:

- http://www.qbasicnews.com/qboho/qckinstr.shtml
- http://www.qbasicnews.com/qboho/qckadvr.instrrr.shtml

If you just want to count the lines of a text file rather than looking for LF characters in a string, you could do something like this:

```
Dim lineCount As Integer
lineCount = 0

Dim f As Integer
f = FreeFile  ' Automatic detection of next free file handle

Open "MYTEXT.TXT" For Input As #f
Do Until Eof(f)
    Line Input #f, temp$
    lineCount = lineCount + 1
Loop
Close #f

Print "The text file consists of "; Ltrim$(Str$(lineCount)); " lines."
Sleep: End
```

But watch out: The `LINE INPUT` count method will only work for DOS/Windows line endings (CrLf = Chr$(13)+Chr$(10) = \r\n). If the text file has UNIX-like line endings (\n only), all lines in the file will become a single string and the counting script above will always return "1 lines" as result.

An alternative approach in that case is opening the file in `BINARY` mode and checking it byte by byte. If Chr$(10) is encountered, than a line count variable is incremented.

```
DIM lineCount AS INTEGER
lineCount = 0

DIM f AS INTEGER
f = FREEFILE  ' Automatic detection of next free file handle

DIM buffer AS STRING
buffer = SPACE$(1)

OPEN "MYTEXT.TXT" FOR BINARY AS #f
DO UNTIL EOF(f)
    GET #f, , buffer
    IF (buffer = CHR$(10)) THEN
        lineCount = lineCount + 1
    END IF
LOOP
CLOSE #f

PRINT "The text file consists of "; LTRIM$(STR$(lineCount)); " lines."
SLEEP: END
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample program to count lines in a file using binary file i/o.

```
REM sample program to count lines in a file in QB64.
' declare filename buffer
CONST xbuflen = 32767 ' can be changed
DIM SHARED xbuffer AS STRING * XBUFLEN
DIM SHARED Lines.Counted AS DOUBLE
' get filename
PRINT "Enter filename";: INPUT Filename$
' start file count
IF _FILEEXISTS(Filename$) THEN
    X = FREEFILE
    OPEN Filename$ FOR BINARY SHARED AS #X LEN = xbuflen
    IF LOF(X) > 0 THEN
        DO UNTIL EOF(X)
            ' get file buffer
            GET X, , xbuffer
            ' count bytes in buffer
            FOR L = 1 TO xbuflen
                IF MID$(xbuffer, L, 1) = CHR$(10) THEN
                    Lines.Counted = Lines.Counted + 1#
                END IF
            NEXT
        LOOP
    END IF
    CLOSE #X
END IF
PRINT "Lines in file"; Lines.Counted
END
```

Comment: Using a large buffer for binary i/o is quicker than reading by bytes.